# How to abandon "mission board"-mission

Tags: no-mans-sky

I got the "mission board"-mission. Unfortunately I have activated this mission in  a abandoned system with only a [abandoned space station](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Space_station#Abandoned_station).

There is no chance to visit a working mission board in this system. Every attempt to activate/deactive this mission in another system tells me something like "go to the other system". Even the Teleporter shows the symbol for this mission for the abandoned space station (without anything else then a Teleporter and a Galactic Trade Terminal inside).

There is no "Cancel" option for this mission and pressing the middle mouse button doesn't work either on the Log page.

Do you know any other method to cancel or reset or relocate such a mission?
I would even use a save game editor to get rid of this mission.

Answer (score 2):

Since talking to a space station attendant is the only in-game option to abandon missions, 
**I think a Save Game Editor is indeed your best bet**.

An editor which seems to be able to do what you want it to do, is [*NMSSaveEditor*](https://github.com/goatfungus/NMSSaveEditor). * 

There is a description of how to change mission statuses in the editor, [here](https://github.com/goatfungus/NMSSaveEditor/issues/36#issuecomment-409757738).** 

Below you will find the outlines:

> If you open the *Raw JSON Editor* [part of the editor], navigate to this location:
>
> *./PlayerStateData/MissionProgress/[MISSION_NUM]* 
>   
> (Where *[MISSION_NUM]*
>   is a number representing that mission in your master acquired missions
>   list).
>
> In there, at the top of each mission container, you'll see something
>   like this:
>
> { 
>   
> "Mission":"^WEAPGUY4", 
>   
> "Progress":8, <--(Do NOT delete that comma!)
>   
> "Seed":0, 
>   
> "Data":0, 
>   
> ... ... ...
>
> What you'll need to do is identify your mission, in this case it will
>   be something like what you see above.
>   The entry you need to change is this one:
>
> "Progress":[X]
>
> The value of [X] increments on each successful completion of a single
>   mission stage.
>   
> Once you save it, exit NMSSE, restart the game, and the mission should show completed.

The ^WEAPGUYx identifiers are for armourer missions, so your identifier will be different. In your case, you might want to change the value to "-1", as this seemed to resolve an issue someone mentions [in the same thread](https://github.com/goatfungus/NMSSaveEditor/issues/36#issuecomment-410786205).

<sup>* This seems to be the GitHub version of the popular [(NMSSE - No Man's Sky Save Editor)](https://nomansskymods.com/mods/no-mans-sky-save-editor/), but, to download the latter, you will need an (unpaid) account.</sup>

<sup>** Before editing, make sure to make a backup of your save file!</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much @joachim. Do you have an idea, which identifier this could be for the mission board?

Comment: I searched for it, but wasn't able to find it. If you can upload your save file I could take a look at it.

Comment: I try to locate it first by myself. Otherwise, I will let you know where to download it .-) Thanks for your offer!

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have found a workaround. After upgrading my starship with an A-class [Hyperdrive-Upgrade](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Hyperdrive_Upgrade) I made a jump to a system about 800 light-years away.
After visiting the next space station and pressing <kbd>P</kbd> for my Log, I saw a new RED galaxy map icon in front of my "visit mission board"-mission.

Thanks to my previous internet search, I knew I could press the middle mouse button over this mission entry blindly. HEUREKA! I got the long awaited "Mission resetted" message and the task to visit the next mission board nearby.

Maybe this can help others in the same situation too? Would be nice to hear some voices from other travellers.